# Django 1.5, CSRF, Login and Clients that Do Not Allow Cookies

Tags: django, cookies, authentication, csrf

The basic problem is this: when users who don't allow cookies try to login to my Django site, they get an CSRF error and are redirected to a 403 Forbidden page. It would be much better if they got a message telling them they must allow cookies.

I am thinking of dealing with this by setting CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW and just displaying a page saying that cookies are required. The assumption being that the only way a legitimate user could get a CSRF failure is by not allowing cookies.

However, when I look at the Django code, it seems that it is possible to display no cookies error on the login form. Here is the clean method of django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm:

```
def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

    if username and password:
        self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username,
                                       password=password)
        if self.user_cache is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid_login'] % {
                    'username': self.username_field.verbose_name
                })
        elif not self.user_cache.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['inactive'])
    self.check_for_test_cookie()
    return self.cleaned_data

def check_for_test_cookie(self):
    if self.request and not self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['no_cookies'])
```

It looks like it should display a no cookies error message. But when I run with cookies disabled the CSRF error prevents the clean method from running.

What am I missing here?

**Update:**
I tried setting CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW to my own handler. The handler is passed a string explaining the failure. In this case I get "CSRF cookie not set.", which is good enough to detect cookies being disabled.

Comment: Did you add the `django.core.context_processors.csrf` context processor as well in your `settings.py`?

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding that context processor. No change. Just to be clear, everything works well when the client allows cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by setting a *test cookie*.

It's there in [Django's documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#setting-test-cookies) how you can implement this.

From Django's docs:

> As a convenience, Django provides an easy way to test whether the user's browser accepts cookies. Just call the `set_test_cookie()` method of request.session in a view, and call `test_cookie_worked()` in a subsequent view – not in the same view call.

Which means, if the client hasn't enabled cookies in his browser, instead of the *403 error* he'll be shown a message to enable cookies **after** he clicks the *login* button.